# Can you use Async Zeep to call a SOAP service behind Basic Auth?

Tags: python, soap, async-await, python-asyncio, zeep

I'm trying to turn a previously working synchronous usage of the Zeep library into the Async version of this. On a request to the WSDL, the transport will always return a 404.

The following is the sync implementation and is working as intended.

```py
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
transport = Transport(session=session)

return Client(config_url, transport=transport)
```

However, when I change this to an async implementation (using httpx) it will return a Transport Error. The only message in this transport error is `401`.

```py
http_client = httpx.Client()
http_client.auth = (username, password)
http_client.verify = True
transport = AsyncTransport(session=http_client)

return AsyncClient(config_url, transport=transport)
```

Am I using async Zeep correctly? According to the [docs](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/client.html#caching-of-wsdl-and-xsd-files) it should work like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Apparently the interface isn't exactly the same. To instantiate a AsyncClient for zeep with basic auth, you'll need to create a Sync and Async client.

This is because zeep fetches the WSDL in a synchronous manner, and then executes the requests asynchronously. This means that the `wsdl_client` must be synchronous and the `client` must be ansynchronous!

```py
async_client = httpx.AsyncClient(
   auth=(username, password),
   verify=True
)
wsdl_client = httpx.Client(
    auth=(username, password),
    verify=True
)

transport = AsyncTransport(client=async_client, wsdl_client=wsdl_client)

return AsyncClient(config_url, transport=transport)
```

With this, we can now await all service requests as described in the docs.